# Permission errors unit-testing Google Cloud Functions calling firestore db

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I'm following the guide at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing, but I always get " FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions" when I run my test. I have the correct `service-account.json` file and I'm setting up `firebase-functions-test` with it (that part goes without error).

I've tried it with the emulator running (setting the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST var), and without it (which I assume uses live data) but I always get this error, as soon as my code under test does a db request such as:

```
  data = await db().collection('/machines').get()
```

So my function under test is getting called, but it just can't do anything.
I also tried calling `firebase.initializeApp()` the same way I do in my front-end app, but that doesn't help, although without it I get the error telling me to call Firebase App.initializeApp().

`firebase use` is set to my current project.

I also tried running my test as `firebase emulators:exec jest`, no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the complete, minimal code that you're using. We should be able to reproduce the issue using exactly what you provide in the question.

Comment: As usual, once I cut it down to a complete, minimal example, I found my bug. :-) Have to do `import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'; const app = admin.initializeApp(); const db=admin.firestore()`. Wasn't a test bug at all, but a code bug. Thanks!